# .netcore asp-for decimal loses decimal places

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am running into an issue where I am losing decimal places when using the asp-for tag helper in my view. It seems to always round up to 2 decimals, while I want to have it round up to 3 decimals (in this case).

I can see in my debugger that the value in the Model has 3 decimal places as e[image]

But then in my view, it's being displayed as `1.28` instead of `1.275`:
[image]

This is my form's view, as you can see there's nothing special really going on (the `asp-has-error` tag helper is a custom tag helper for this project):

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="RatePercentage" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input asp-for="RatePercentage" asp-has-error="@Html.HasErrorFor(m => m.RatePercentage)" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can get 3 decimal places to show here?

Comment: Do you have any attributes on the `RatePercentage` model property?

Comment: No attributes no.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's just the default. You can use the `DisplayFormat` attribute to make it whatever you like:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:[format]}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal RatePercentage { get; set; }
```

Where `[format]` is the format string you want. See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Comment: If anyone would rather not click on the useful links above with all format options, the format to show with three decimal places is:
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N3}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Answer (score 3):

Another way to stop the tag-helper from applying this default formatting is to explicitly specify the `input` element's `type` attribute and assign it as `text` like so:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="RatePercentage" …/>
```

Then you get the 'raw' decimal value in the input control and you can use an edit-mask or format it yourself some other way and not automatically lose the precision of the value that happens otherwise.