# Decimal type loses precision in .ASP.net Core Razor binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have been facing issue where .net core rounding decimal values to 2 decimal places we want more precision of upto 5 decimal places. Issue already discussed   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985740/netcore-asp-for-decimal-loses-decimal-places) question. The solution provided doesn't seem to be very elegant. Is there a a way to override this default behavior

Comment: I see no indication that .NET Core is "losing precising" here - just that the Razor binding has some default formatting. If you believe it's really .NET Core rather than Razor's default formatting, could you provide a [mcve] as a *console* application? For example, what does `decimal m = 1.23456789m; Console.WriteLine(m);` show for you?

Comment: (And if it really *is* just Razor binding+formatting as I expect, you already have an answer in the other question. I don't think asking a new question for the same thing is going to give you a different result.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your info i Have updated the question accordingly. The question was little old so thought may get a some other better solution as i Need this at application level

Answer (score 1):

1) Use decimal(18, 5) in SQL Server table

2) Add step="0.00001" in your html input or whatever

```
<input type="number" asp-for="Amount" step="0.00001" />
```

Result

[image]

[image]

This is still old. It has been around since old .net framework. Don't understand why you find it so hard to solve. o.o

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp-format to your input tag like this:

```
 <input asp-for='data' asp-format="{0:0.00000}" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write your own tag helper that format the number with 5 decimal places. And it can apply through out the application. This way, you have more control on how/where you display the numbers. And all formatting code/logic is put in 1 place, so easier for you to change in future.